# rounding answers to decimal places

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function calculate() {
var x= document.Form.x.value
var y = document.Form.y.value
if(x> 0 && y> 0){   
var final = x/(y/100*y/100)
document.Form.answer.value = final
if(final < a){
document.Form.meaning.value = "A"
}
if(final > a && final < b){
document.Form.meaning.value = "B"
}
if(final > b && final < c){
document.Form.meaning.value = "C"
}
if(final > d){
document.Form.meaning.value = "D"
}
}
else{
alert("Please Fill form in correctly")
}
}
//-->
</script>

<div class=form2>
<form name="Form">
x: <input type="text" name="x" size="10"><br />
y: <input type="text" name="y" size="10"><br />
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()"><br />
Answer: <input type="text" name="answer" size="10"><br />
This Means: <input type="text" name="meaning" size="25"><br />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
</div>
```

I am using the above to calculate based on peoples inputs  X and Y...

I am getting the desired answers however is giving a long list of decimal places.

I am looking for a way to round each answer up to a max of 2 decimal places.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Why is this tagged php?

Comment: I marked this question in PHP as I was putting the code into calculator.php script

Comment: Tags are used to show where the question belongs. This is not a php question. Use the tags where the problem is. Not all tags that can use. Excessive tag usage usually leads to questions put on hold or being deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.ceil()` will round up and `Math.floor()` will round down to the nearest whole number.

You'll need to bump up the answer by a factor of 100 to do the rounding and then divide it back by 100 to go back to decimals.

Also, there was a lot about your code that does not follow modern, best-practices and standards as well as some problems with your `if` logic.

See the comments inline for details:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // Always get references to the elelements themselves, not property values.
  // That way, if you decide you need to access another property somewhere else
  // you don't have to re-scan the DOM for the same element. Also, access elements
  // using modern standards.
  var x= document.querySelector("input[name='x']");
  var y= document.querySelector("input[name='y']");
  var ans= document.getElementById("answer");
  var m = document.getElementById("meaning");
  var btn = document.getElementById("calc");
  
  // Set up button click event handler here, in the JavaScript, not in the HTML
  btn.addEventListener("click", calculate);

  function calculate() {
  
    // Next, always trim off any possible leading or trailing spaces from user input
    var xVal = x.value.trim();
    var yVal = y.value.trim();
  
    if(xVal > 0 && yVal > 0){   
  
      var final = xVal/(yVal/100*yVal/100);
      console.log("Answer = " + final);
    
      // First, multiply answer by 100
      final = final * 100;
      console.log("Answer times 100 = " + final);
  
      // Next, round answer up to nearest whole number
      final = Math.ceil(final);
      console.log("Answer times 100, rounded up to nearest whole number = " + final);
  
      // Now, divide by 100 to go back to decimals
      final = final / 100;
      console.log("Answer divided back by 100 = " + final);

      ans.textContent = final;
      
      // These should be else if, not one if after another since only
      // one of the conditions will be true.
      if(final < a){
        m.textContent = "A"
      } else if(final > a && final < b){
        m.textContent = "B"
      } else if(final > b && final < c){
        m.textContent = "C"
      } else if(final > d){
        m.textContent = "D"
      }
    } else{
      alert("Please Fill form in correctly")
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.left { 
  float:left;
  width:100px; 
}

.results {
  margin-top:1em;
}

.after {
  clear:both;
  margin-top:2em;
}
```

```html
<div class=form2>
 <form name="Form">
   <!-- The text that accompanies the fields should be <label> elements
        for better accessibility and for easier styling.   -->
   <label for="x" class="left">x: </label><input type="text" name="x" id="x" size="10"><br>
   <label for="y" class="left">y: </label><input type="text" name="y" id="y" size="10">
   
   <!-- Don't use inline HTML event handling attributes.
        Do you JavaScript separately. -->
   <div><input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calc"></div>
   
   <!-- Don't use form fields for displaying data. -->
   <div class="results">
     <span class="left">Answer: </span><span id="answer"></span><br>
     <span class="left">This Means: </span><span id="meaning"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="after">
     <input type="reset" value="Reset">
   </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This is excellemt

Answer (score 0):

Use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) function to round. Ex : `final.toFixed(2);`

```html
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function calculate() {
var x= document.Form.x.value
var y = document.Form.y.value
if(x> 0 && y> 0){   
var final = x/(y/100*y/100)
document.Form.answer.value = final.toFixed(2);
if(final < a){
document.Form.meaning.value = "A"
}
if(final > a && final < b){
document.Form.meaning.value = "B"
}
if(final > b && final < c){
document.Form.meaning.value = "C"
}
if(final > d){
document.Form.meaning.value = "D"
}
}
else{
alert("Please Fill form in correctly")
}
}
//-->
</script>

<div class=form2>
<form name="Form">
x: <input type="text" name="x" size="10"><br />
y: <input type="text" name="y" size="10"><br />
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()"><br />
Answer: <input type="text" name="answer" size="10"><br />
This Means: <input type="text" name="meaning" size="25"><br />
<input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
</div>
```